# How add 0 when TruncWeek's week no result in Django Query?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want query the issue's count of group by weekly.

```
query1 = MyModel.object.filter(issue_creator__in=group.user_set.all()).\
    annotate(week=TruncWeek('issue_creat_date')).values('week').annotate(count=Count('id')).order_by('week'))
```

the query result is OK. the queryset result:

```
[
    {'week': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 3, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Stockholm' CEST+2:00:00 DST>), 'count': 9}, 
    {'week': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 10, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Stockholm' CEST+2:00:00 DST>), 'count': 12}, 
    {'week': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 17, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Stockholm' CEST+2:00:00 DST>), 'count': 10}, 
    {'week': datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 7, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Stockholm' CEST+2:00:00 DST>), 'count': 1}, 
    {'week': datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 14, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Stockholm' CEST+2:00:00 DST>), 'count': 6}, 
    {'week': datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 21, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Stockholm' CEST+2:00:00 DST>), 'count': 11}, 
    {'week': datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 28, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Stockholm' CEST+2:00:00 DST>), 'count': 1}
]
```

but 20220101-20220301 has 9 weeks:

```
[
    datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 3, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Stockholm' CEST+2:00:00 DST>), 
    datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 10, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Stockholm' CEST+2:00:00 DST>), 
    datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 17, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Stockholm' CEST+2:00:00 DST>),
    datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 24, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Stockholm' CEST+2:00:00 DST>), 
    datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 31, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Stockholm' CEST+2:00:00 DST>), 
    datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 7, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Stockholm' CEST+2:00:00 DST>), 
    datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 14, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Stockholm' CEST+2:00:00 DST>), 
    datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 21, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Stockholm' CEST+2:00:00 DST>), 
    datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 28, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Stockholm' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)
]
```

I want add zero when that week no result as this result:

```
[
    {'week': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 3, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Stockholm' CEST+2:00:00 DST>), 'count': 9}, 
    {'week': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 10, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Stockholm' CEST+2:00:00 DST>), 'count': 12}, 
    {'week': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 17, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Stockholm' CEST+2:00:00 DST>), 'count': 10}, 
    {'week': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 24, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Stockholm' CEST+2:00:00 DST>), 'count': 0}, 
    {'week': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 31, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Stockholm' CEST+2:00:00 DST>), 'count': 0}, 
    {'week': datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 7, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Stockholm' CEST+2:00:00 DST>), 'count': 1}, 
    {'week': datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 14, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Stockholm' CEST+2:00:00 DST>), 'count': 6}, 
    {'week': datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 21, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Stockholm' CEST+2:00:00 DST>), 'count': 11}, 
    {'week': datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 28, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Stockholm' CEST+2:00:00 DST>), 'count': 1}
]
```

how to write the right queryset?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't do that in a `QuerySet`. You will have to post-process the list and insert rows with `0` for the missing ones.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes, I did that as you say. I feel is not elegant。